# Error creating BackendService: googleapi: Error 403: Required 'compute.backendServices.create' permission for 'projects/myproject-137813/global/backen

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, devops, terraform-provider-gcp, google-cloud-iam

On **GCP**, I'm trying to create **a Backend Service** with this **Terraform** code below:

```js
resource "google_compute_backend_service" "default" {
  name      = "backend-service"

  backend {
    group = google_compute_region_network_endpoint_group.cloudrun_neg.id
  }
}
```

But I got this error below:

> Error creating BackendService: googleapi: Error 403: Required
> 'compute.backendServices.create' permission for
> 'projects/myproject-137813/global/backendServices/backend-service',
> forbidden

So now, I'm trying to add a role to solve this error above but there are too many roles to choose:

[image]

What role do I need to choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to choose the role **"Compute Network Admin"** to create **a Backend Service**:

[image]

In addition, you can choose the more abstract role **"Compute Admin"** to create **a Backend Service**:

[image]